# SignedXml.CheckSignature works in .NET 1.1, but fails in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I have the following SignedXml code. This code works just perfectly in .NET 1.1, but when I run this in .NET 3.5, the method `signedXml.CheckSignature()` keeps returning false.
**With regard to the `SignedXml` class, did something change between .Net 1.1 and 3.5?** I'm puzzeled here! Can you guys help me out here?

```
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml();

        // Get public key
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("MyLib.Application.dll");
        Stream keyStream =
            assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyKey.xml");
        StreamReader keyReader = new StreamReader(keyStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string publicKeyXml = keyReader.ReadToEnd();
        keyReader.Close();

        // Load and set key
        DSA dsaKeyPair = DSA.Create();
        dsaKeyPair.FromXmlString(publicKeyXml);
        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        keyInfo.AddClause(new DSAKeyValue(dsaKeyPair));
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;


        // Load and set data
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(signedXmlData);

        XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");
        signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

        string returnXml = null;
        if (signedXml.CheckSignature())
        {
            XmlElement dataElement = signedXml.GetIdElement(xmlDocument, "LicenseElement");
            returnXml = dataElement.InnerXml;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo; was the problem for me. When I used the key as an argument to CheckSignature() then it worked - I was able to load 1.1 signed xml in a 2.0 application.

Just remove the KeyInfo altogether:

```
  string returnXml = null;
    if (signedXml.CheckSignature(dsaKeyPair))
    {
        XmlElement dataElement = signedXml.GetIdElement(xmlDocument, "LicenseElement");
        returnXml = dataElement.InnerXml;
    }
```